# SQL Server select query taking more time when using order by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using `sql server 2008 r2`. one table having `14000 records`. with out using order by it returns the result in 0 sec. but when i use order by query it takes 1 min to return result. please help me to overcome from this problem.

Comment: And we have to guess the query !

Comment: Probaly you need to add an index

Comment: Is the turbo button on your CPU pressed in or out? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try creating an [index](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp) on the column that you are ordering by.

If you already have an index you will have to learn how to use SQL Server Profiler to get suggestions of other factors that might be effecting performance.

A good source on SQL Server Profiler [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/03/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-profiler-2/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply..

I have sorted out this issue. I am using two different database tables in that query using inner join. i have replaced that with left outer join then its working fine.

thanks for your comments.